# Are there CSS generators

Tags: html, css

We provide a default **CSS file** (and the HTML mock-up) which they modify (e.g., color, background-image) to fit with their intended look and feel and feedback the CSS files to us.

Now the problem comes. We have a dozen of partners. If we need add new selectors in default CSS, we also need to add default CSS selectors to **all partners CSS files** first. We then send the new CSS files to partners to modify. It's a maintenance nightmare for our web designers.

Is there any CSS generator solution that we can just modify the CSS template and then populate the changes to all CSS files?

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Why can't you just overwrite the default stylesheet with a custom one, loaded after? Are you looking for something like CSS variables? Can you provide more specific details and/or examples?

Answer (score 7):

The main CSS generators/preprocessors are [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/). More reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411066/less-vs-sass-vs

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite understand what you are trying to do, but I will share some CSS generators that I use regularly:

1. If you want to generate CSS automatically from the markup online for free, then you need this: 
   http://beecss.theextremewebdesigns.com/
2. If you already have (messy) CSS & you would like to clean/minify it online for free, then you need this:
   http://beecss.theextremewebdesigns.com/css_clean_css_minify/

As @Wesley mentioned, if you can post more examples/specifications, perhaps then I can help more.

Answer (score 0):

There are no CSS generator as you like. But we can get css generator (on internet) from the scratch for a image mockup.

Comment: Could you clarify? What you're saying does not make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, newly founded on the web:

http://www.css3generator.net

You can adjust different parameters, and compare differentes, and it provides the css codes.
Great when you forgot how to write some pieces of code and syntaxes.